# Does the following metric metrize the weak*topology on the state space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Let A be a finite-dimensional C*-algebra.  In a paper of Rieffel, it is shown that its state space, S(A), equipped with the energy metric, is isometrically embedded in a Hilbert space. Does this imply that the energy metric metrizes the weak* topology on S(A)?

Comment: Would you mind introducing this metric here? Thank you.

Comment: Seconding @Tomek's remark. However there is one more thing to be said, if your algebra $A$ is finite dimensional (in the sense that it is a finite dimensional vector space) then all metrics induce the same topology on the dual. So if your energy metric extends to the entire dual in a way that addition and scalar multiplication are continuous, then it metrizises the weak* topology on $S(A)$. All this is by virtue of $A$ being finite dimensional.

Comment: The C*-algebra does happen to be finite-dimensional!  What do you recommend as a good reference for this fact?